# Represent any set of characters in a regex expression

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I want to treat expressions like these:

expression 1 -> **sum$4,8,'x'$**

expression 2 -> **sum$2,15,'(x^3+3)/(x+1)'$**

and i am using regular expressions to recognize the pattern:

```
sum\$[0-9]+[,][0-9]+[,]['][.]*[\w]*[']\$
```

But it only works for expression 1, why dot (.) which represents any character seems like is not working? Do I have to treat the parenthesis in a special way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is a meta character that will match any 1 character. There are other meta characters like `\d` which will match 1 letter between 0-9. **SOME** of the meta characters loose their special meaning inside character class `[]`. So dot inside character class `[]` will not be a meta character any more and will  be treated as literal dot.

`.*` and `.*?` are two different things. Former will greedily match everything and later is lazy. For eg. Take a string like: `abbcbbbc`. Now
`a.*c` will match the complete string `abbcbbbc` while `a.*?c` will match only `abbc`

You can try Something like this.

```
sum\$\d+,\d+,'.*?'\$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6PEfBh/1

Answer (score 0):

The way `[]` work is they match characters *exactly* so in your case you have to have the `.` without `[]` like so:

```
sum\$[0-9]+[,][0-9]+[,]['].*[\w]*[']\$
```

This regex also matches expression 2

Comment: Why this `'[.]*'` does not work? what is the difference of using this (apart of working) `'.*?'`   @oschlueter

Comment: `[.]*` matches a literal dot character, for example ".....". It's what I mean with an *exact* character match. When you have the dot inside the `[]` it doesn't have the special meaning but is just a dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sum\$[0-9]+[,][0-9]+[,]['][^']*[\w]*[']\$
```

Replaced [.] with [^']